# How can I get metadata from a spreadsheet using gspread?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, python-3.7

I have a spreadsheet with a significant amount of data and metadata and am trying to access it in python 3.7 through `gspread`. I have managed to add metadata to a sheet using the `batch_update` method, which calls [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) in the API. However I can not find a way to do a [metadata search](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata/search) as `dataFilter` types are not valid inputs for `batchUpdate` and I can not find an implementation of the `search` call.

```
payload = {
    "requests": [\
        {\
            "createDeveloperMetadata": {
                "developerMetadata": {
                    "metadataKey": "Hello",
                    "metadataValue": " World",
                    "location": {
                        "spreadsheet": True
                    },
                    "visibility": "DOCUMENT"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

spreadsheet.batch_update(payload)
```

Any suggestions for how i can retrieve the metadata I added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the developer metadata you put from a Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Spreadsheet with Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, the developer metadata cannot be directly retrieved using gspread, while the developer metadata can be put using the method of `batch_update`. (I think that this might be resolved in the future update.) So as the current workaround, I would like to propose to use [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) by using the credential for gspread.

#### Modified script:

```
from apiclient import discovery

service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

spreadsheetId = '###'  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
body = {'dataFilters': [{'developerMetadataLookup': {'metadataKey': 'Hello'}}]}
request = service.spreadsheets().developerMetadata().search(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=body)
response = request.execute()
print(response)
```

- In this modified script, `credentials` of `client = gspread.authorize(credentials)` is used to `service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)`.
- When above script is run, `metadataKey` of `Hello` is searched, and the result is returned.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.developerMetadata.search](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata/search)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.